# How shall I "Unsuspend" my suspended Heroku Application?

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres, suspend

I got a mail some moments ago saying my deployed Django application has been suspended. I deployed it a few weeks ago and it has been running fine. No reason was given as to the cause of the suspension. And when I try to access the application, all I see is the image below.

[image: Heroku App Suspended]

I'd appreciate any advice on what to do. Thank you.

Comment: Been paying your bills?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [we can't answer customer service questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Contact Heroku support.

Comment: @Iain I made use of their free tier service

Comment: @Chris I tried creating a ticket but I got prompted that they don't offer such support for free tier applications and they directed me to find answers from the community here. Not sure what to do honestly

Comment: @Wolemercy, I'm not sure what to tell you. Customer service questions aren't on-topic here. Please read the link I provided above to understand why. You'll have to resolve this with Heroku. Log into their portal and poke around. Look for logs, errors, notifications, etc. that might explain what is going on.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, alright. Thanks